# What data on violence against women in the U.S. is available?

Tags: data-request, usa

The best source seems to be the National Crime Victimization Survey, and especially their victim characteristics reports at http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=92

Any others? Any hints on interpreting and working with this data?

Answer (score 3):

The FBI provides summary data on crime statistics. These tables cover a variety of categories and geographic regions (national, state, county, Metropolitan Statistical Areas (MSA)).

The start page is here:
http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/crime-in-the-u.s/2010/crime-in-the-u.s.-2010/violent-crime

The world bank has a Excel spreadsheet for violent crimes against women on a per country basis. The data is summary (percent/totals).

http://web.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/TOPICS/EXTSOCIALDEVELOPMENT/EXTCPR/0,,contentMDK:22488819~menuPK:6835249~pagePK:148956~piPK:216618~theSitePK:407740,00.html

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [National Incident-based Reporting System](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/NIBRS/) data (stored at ICPSR). I've not personally worked with these data, but this is based on police reports whereas the NCVS is based on survey self-reports.